# How to mock all files in a folder in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have files as follows

```
widgets
|
 --tabs
    |
     -- __mocks_
        |
         -- index.ts
     -- index.ts
 --button
    |
     -- __mocks_
        |
         -- index.ts
     -- index.ts
```

Its imported/used in files as

```
import { Button } from 'common/widgets/button';
```

I can individually mock each of these.

```
jest.mock('common/widgets/tabs');
jest.mock('common/widgets/button');
```

But is there a way to mock them all like add all these to file and import them or do like below with a common mock folder and an index file.

```
jest.mock('common/widgets');
```

Comment: I posted an answer. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way (P.S. All functions and function calls are just for demonstration:

> Folder structure

[image]

*widgets/button/index.js*

```
// demonstration
const someFunction = () => {
  console.log("widgets/button")
}

export default someFunction;
```

*widgets/tabs/index.js*

```
// demonstration
const someFunction = () => {
  console.log("widgets/tabs")
}

export default someFunction;
```

*widgets/index.js*

```
export { default as Button } from './button/index';
export { default as Tabs } from './tabs/index';
```

**-- Usage**
You can import the functions as named import in any file. E.G.:
*/any/file.js*

```
import { Button, Tabs } from 'common/widgets'
...
```

So, you should be able to import them into a single mock file.

*mock/index.js*

```
jest.mock('common/widgets');
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I am aware of this. I cant import all of these into same file as they may be interdependent . is there any other way

Comment: You can use Enyzme, as [https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-unit-test-multiple-components-wrapped-in-one-page-ReactJS-using-Jest] says, *you can still use the mount function provided by Enzyme which will mount the page and all of it’s nested component, then you can perform any expected actions you’d like to manipulate the page in the test*

Answer (score 1):

When we import any module in the test file then jest checks whether there is an mock implementation of that module is present in the `./__mocks__` directory or not. If jest founds it then jest will simple mock that module.

Here in your case, you already have mock modules in your `./__mocks__` directories. **You don't need `jest.mock()` api to mock your modules.**

Jest mock is meant to mock modules not directories which contains modules.

Comment: any link that corroborates this coz in my experience it has been same. Any jest config we need to set for this to auto happen.